# Adding a callback to a function that was loaded from an external URL via getScript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am loading an URL via jQuery's getScript method:

```
$.getScript(url, function () {      
    init(function() {
        console.log('test')
    });     
    // Can I add the above callback, so that, after the init has finished, I would see "test" in the console?
    elOverlay.show();
});
```

After the URL has been loaded, I have access to the init() function.

This function is out of my control and has no callback.

Can I add a callback to this function?

Comment: depends on where this `init` comes from, and what it does. you can have more if you provide us some more code.

Comment: Unless the function accepts a callback or returns a promise, you're out of luck. I assume the `init` function is async, right, since that's the only reason this would be necessary?

Comment: the only way you have is going thru the init function and figure out the async part and push your callback in it, unless as @Jason P has said the function itself accepts a callback

Comment: The function does accept a callback - and I cannot edit it - it belogs to another domain out of my control - so I'm out of luck :)

Comment: @webmasters One option that isn't ideal, but may be the best you can do, is try to find something (a DOM node, some data, etc) that indicates that the `init()` function has completed, then set up a `setInterval` to check for that.

Answer (score 0):

One possible solution could be creating new function which includes main function and callback. Here's exammple what i mean:

```
function callbackInit(cb) {

    var status = false; // for extra assurance that the script is executed

    init(); // run the main function

    status = true;
    if(status) { 
      if(typeof callback === 'function') { // check if callback is function
          cb(); // then run the callback
      }
    }
}
```